# I can not create kernel module in my debian 9

Tags: linux-kernel, debian

I want to create a new kernel module and I have some documents for that job.I have a simple.c docs and have a Makefile docs.These 2 docs are in a folder.
I open terminal and I go to the folder and I want to add my kernel module but there is a problem when I enter "make" command.

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64/build M=/home/emre/OpSys modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64/build: There is no such file or directory. It stopped.
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then I decide to update kernel versions or linux headers for my linux.
After all I learnt my linux version thanks to "uname -r".

```
root@debian:/home/emre/OpSys# apt-get install linux-headers-4.9-0-8-amd64
Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti
Bağımlılık ağacı oluşturuluyor       
Durum bilgisi okunuyor... Bitti      
E: linux-headers-4.9-0-8-amd64 paketi bulunamadı
E: 'linux-headers-4.9-0-8-amd64' ifadesine eşleşen herhangi bir paket bulunamadı
E: 'linux-headers-4.9-0-8-amd64' düzenli ifadesini içeren herhangi bir paket bulunamadı
```

If you do not know Turkish I can explain for you.
 At above linux gives me error which it can not find linux-headers-4.9-0-8-amd64 packages.

After that I tried some commands for updating but I cant handle it.Can you give me some advices for the topic  ? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a simple typo in the package name. It should be "linux-headers-4.9.0-8-amd64".

Answer (score 0):

Like Ian have describe. I think it's a typo for package name.
Also you should try `apt-get update` and check if it's the same kernel version that you  want to install.

Comment: Thanks your interest.However I noticed that there was 2 kernel version in my debian 9.One of them is 3.bla bla version and the other one is at  the above.Thus my "build" folder is under the other kernel version.That's way I took above error.I tried to change my kernel versions but I can not afford it.After all I installed Debian 10 and I solved.